# Can't find Smart Lock on Huawei Y6 on Lollipop 5.1.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, huawei, smart-lock

My phone is Huawei Y6.

- I already have a pin lock.
- Enabled **Smart Lock (Google)** in Trusted Agents.

But I still can't find Smart Lock feature anywhere.

[image: upper part]

[image: bottom part]

Answer (score 1):

I have a Huawei 4C with EMUI 3.1 (Lollipop 5.1.1) and don't have Smart Lock setting anywhere either. I think it's just that EMUI might have simply overwritten default security settings menu, and now that option isn't accessible from there.

Comment: I removed the question on your post. Take note that this is not a forum, but Q&A site. Answer is to answer the question, not to reply to any. However, your guess is as good as mine, since when researching about Huawei, Lollipop and Smart Lock, I found others have the same issue, as noted on [this post on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61872572&postcount=44)

Answer (score 0):

It does have a Smart Lock feature at least on Stock and CyanogenMod build.

On Stock Android (5.1.1): Settings > Lock Screen > Smart Lock.

[image: SmartLock on Android 5.1.1]

Comment: Are you specific with Huawei y6 or just lollipop 5.1.1 ? because I do not have a lock screen option.This is how it looks on settings.. 
   http://i.imgur.com/DJYsCBV.png

Comment: @NirmalSeneviratne PhoneArena says that Huawei Y6 runs on **Huawei EMUI 3.1 UI**. As much as I know, This ROM is close to Stock Android and it should definitely have that feature.

Comment: @NirmalSeneviratne Is there **Lock Screen** option in Settings?

Comment: There is **Screen lock & passwords** option only, no **lock screen** option.You can see all options related to security of settings page in the screenshot in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. Huawei Honor 4x after upgrading to Lollipop the Smart Lock UI Is Missing. After Connecting a new Bluetooth device it had even asked me once or twice if I want to use this device to unlock the phone so there seem to be working in the background but no way to control it. Obvious bug.